# Error load content file type .fbx

Tags: xna, load, xna-4.0

I have one model fighter su39. But when I load it into my game there is an error about importer.

> Error  1   Cannot autodetect which importer to use for "ShipGame\Models\ship\air_su39_cockpit_c.tif". There are no importers which handle this file type. Specify the importer that handles this file type in your project.

Have any solution for model .fbx attached to file .tif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert an image .tif to .tga or another file type, and edit that model in 3ds max.

Answer (score 0):

The image types you can add, that are supported by the Content Pipeline, are `.bmp`, `.jpg`, `.png` and a few other texture file formats.  `.tif` is not one of them unfortunately.